# How to solve Android resource linking failed error (xml/shortcuts) not found?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

App showing below error app directly run emulator or device scenario. but generate apk no issue occurred. already working good but suddenly this issue occurred

Execution failed for task ':app:processPatientDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed

i tries change kotlin version and also invalidate caches in android studio option and also try delete build folder

Execution failed for task ':app:processPatientDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> /home/kbytez/project/xxxxxxx/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/patientDebug/AndroidManifest.xml:184: error: resource xml/shortcuts (aka com.xxxxx.patient:xml/shortcuts) not found.
> /home/kbytez/project/xxxx/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/patientDebug/AndroidManifest.xml:189: error: resource string/app_id_value (aka com.xxxxx.patient:string/app_id_value) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.[shortcut available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOzxw.png)

Answer (score 1):

And you want to use shortcuts or not? If yes - check if you have shortcuts.xml in res/xml folder and if you have

```
<meta-data
android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

in your manifest file, in `<activity>` section, the same where you have

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

If not - check your manifest and remove above code, if you have it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOzxw.png

Comment: it is xml-v25 - so it's visible only for api 25 or higher version of Android - check your minSdkVersion, if it's lower than 25, you should create shortcuts.xml in xml folder, not xml-v25.

Comment: compileSdkVersion = 33
        minSdkVersion = 25
        targetSdkVersion = 33 my project i give min version 25 but not working. earlier it's working. i not change any plugin but now run time above issue occured

Comment: try to move shortcuts.xml from xml-v25 to just xml - maybe you use some libraries which has min version lower than 25 and maybe this is the problem. And this -v25 is not needed when your min version is 25. And the second thing - try clean project and rebuild it. Sometimes it cleans some old dependences and app start working.

Comment: thanks for your reply. actually our project have 3 apps single project. i tried that way also